# Full page div, fit image to smaller dimension (preserve aspect ratio)?

Tags: html, css

I've been reading quite a bit of answers on this, but simply cannot get it to work. I thought I'd provide a full example, and hopefully I'll get an answer that works for me.

I have this image, `bckg.png`, size 1200x1920, created with Imagemagick `convert -size 1200x1920 gradient:tomato-steelblue -distort SRT 60 bckg.png` (click for full size):

[image: bckg-fs8.png]

I want this displayed in the center of the browser window, such that it is scaled according to the smaller dimension of the browser window, so the aspect ratio is preserved.

<sub>For instance, if the available browser window page area is 887x487, the smaller dimension is the height -- so I'd like the image height scaled to 487px, and preserving aspect ratio, its width would then be 487*(1200/1920) ≈ 305 px</sub>

So, I'm trying the following code, `temp.htm`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
html,body { height:100%; }
/* convert -size 1200x1920 gradient:tomato-steelblue -distort SRT 60 bckg.png */
#background {
  background: url(bckg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100%;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="background">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In Firefox 42, this renders as:

[image: ff-div]

However, what I would have wanted instead, should approximately look like this (I montaged this in an image editor):

[image: ff-div2]

... and basically, regardless of how I resize the browser window, the entire image should be shown inside it, centered.

How can I do this with HTML/CSS? (pre-css3 answers are appreciated as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just switch the `background-size` to `contain` instead of `cover` [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/sqdkyaot/)

```
#background {
    background-size: contain;
```

---

** *Note that* if you want to get rid of the few white pixel margin around on your page top, right, bottom and left sides add this to your `body` css:

```
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Mi-Creativity - works great, am accepting the answer as soon as the 9 minutes expire :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'd rater prefer this one:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
 #background {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H1yb.png') no-repeat center center;
     background-size: auto 100%;
     height:100%;
}
```

in order to obtain a larger compatibility width IE (i didn't test on older version but it should be 7+, maybe 6+)

http://jsfiddle.net/sqdkyaot/4/